# Why Page.PreviousPage timedout, is it sessionState timeout or something else?

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin, cookie-authentication

I am trying to figure out why the following code failed the `null` check and throw the exception after some time, and I am yet to determin what's the reason for the timeout, which I think it is the reason I got the exception message, it's normally happens in the morning next day or after lunch break. But I am still yet able to reliably replicate issue.

```
var prePage = Page.PreviousPage as BasePage;

if (prePage != null)
{
   PageSessionField = prePage.PageSessionField;
}
else
{
   throw new Exception("Null previous page session exception.");
}
```

my first guess it the `sessionState` timeout:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc" timeout="20" useHostingIdentity="false" />
```

But I tried to change the `timeout` value to for example minimum number `1`, but it mostly don't throw the exception as expected.

Otherwise, the Application pool settings in IIS: idle timeout and recycling settings all looks OK to me.

[image: IIS Application pool config section]

**Update:**

1. I've managed to replicate the issue by waiting 30 minutes and comes
   back and refresh the page, and will get the exception caused by
   `Page.PreviousPage` is `null`.
2. It's looks like timeout is caused by `Owin` code which are useing
   Cookie authentication.
3. Looks like something to do with AD FS token expired, see my answer for the evidence I gathered.

Comment: Have you tried to modify timeexpirespan in your application？ If it doesn't fix the problem, it sounds like application pool get recycled for some reason.

Comment: @JokiesDing, you mean `Cookie​Authentication​Options.​Expire​Time​Span`? I was thinking along the line of the application pool, but it's unlikely as when I encounter the issue myself, there is no entry in Event log about application pool recycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the ADFS token we are using for authentication got expired, and after it expired, our website will request another token and after re-direct from the ADFS server during the re-authenticate process, the `PreviousPage` is lost as it's essentially re-direct rather than the server transfer.

I can confirm that by looking at the `TokenLifeTime` by execute power shell on the ADFS server:

```
Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -Name "relying_party"
```

And I got this:
[image]

Apparently `0` means 60 minutes.

And I also managed to capture the Fiddler session with the Token Response form the ADFS server:

```
&lt;wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;>2020-04-21T01:50:36.830Z&lt;/wsu:Expires>
```

Which is one hour after create the token.

I even play around to reduce the `TokentLifetime` to 5 minutes or something using:

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Targetname "relying_party" -TokenLifetime 5
```

Which will reduce the time out session to 5 minutes as expected.

But I still can't get the issue replicated 100% of the time.

Update: I later found this link: [so there three timeout settings on ADFS server alone could affecting the timeout I encountered](https://tristanwatkins.com/coordinating-adfs-2012-r2-token-lifetime-logon-prompt-enforce-revocation-session-duration-public-network/)